# JCR-SQL2 Select all nodes that have child node with specific property value

Tags: xpath, jcr, jcr-sql2

I have the following node structure in the JCR

```
/testNode (mgnl:content)
   |--- child (mgnl:contentNode)
          |--- property : value
```

How can I select all nodes of type `mgnl:content` that have property `child.property = 'value'` using JCR-SQL2? An xpath example would also be greatly appreciated as well as explanation of them.

Also if I want to change the `property=value` equation to a LIKE operation how would I do that?

Comment: can you please the source XML (at least a sample) rather than the outline you've posted? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example